# How to remove double quotes from a variable in a batch file?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, double-quotes

`var` may be double quoted:

```
    set var="Very long text"
```

or without quotes:

```
    set var=Some_Text
```

I would like to get the unquoted text, i.e. `Very long text` in the first case and `Some_Text` in the second one.

How could I remove the double quotes, if exist ?

Comment: Much easier is the following solution I found in Stackoverflow: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5242166/1016343](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5242166/1016343)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [this method](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-dequote.html)?

***See also:*** http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: I found also this solution, which looks nice: `set var=%var:"=%`. Thanks for your time !