# Batch file parameter with spaces, double quotes, pipes

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that needs to be passed a parameter that will include pipes and spaces. Because of the spaces, double quotes need to be attached to the parameter when passing it in. I need to strip off those double quotes and echo the parameter. Normally, using the ~ would let me do this, but I think something about the specific parameters I'm passing in causes a problem. If I do this:

[test1.bat]

```
call test2.bat "Account|Access Level|Description"
```

[test2.bat]

```
echo %1
echo %~1
```

And run test1.bat, I get this output:

```
"Account|Access Level|Description"
'Access' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So how do I remove the double quotes and still have a usable variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use delayed expansion, because it doesn't care about special characters.
The only problem is to get parameter content into a variable, as it can only transfer via a percent expansion.
But in your case this should work.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "str=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !str!
```

Remark, I disable first the delayed expansion, so the ! and ^ aren't modified by the expansion of %1

**EDIT:** The delayed expansion can be disabled or enabled with

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

If enabled, it adds another way of extending variables (`!variable!` instead of `%variable%`), primary to prevent the parenthesis block effect of variables (described at `set /?`).

But the expansion with `!variable!` also prevents the content of any further parsing, because the delayed expansion is the last phase of batch line parsing.
In detail it is explained at
[how does the windows command interpreter cmd exe parse scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

Comment: it worked! thank you so much! can you tell me why it worked? what am i doing when i disable or enable "delayed expansion"?

Comment: How would you pass a single double quote into this? Whenever I try to call a batch file quoting it like `.\blah.cmd "asdf"" 123"` the `echo !str!` outputs two double quotes instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
if "%~2"=="" (
    call %0 "Account|Access Level|Description" dummy
) ELSE (
    setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
    for /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ("%~1") DO @echo.%%A
)
```

Not exactly pretty, but it works. Dealing with special characters is always a pain in batch files...

Comment: How would you pass a literal double-quote into this? When I try (by `.\play2.cmd "a b"" c" dummy`) I get two double quotes echoed instead of 1.